# Update message card in Teams via webhook connector

Tags: webhooks, microsoft-teams, connector

I have a build machine from which I want to post updates in Microsoft Teams. I created a webhook connector for my channel in Teams and I can send a simple POST request to the webhook url to post a message card in Teams with this json payload:

```
{
    "@type": "MessageCard",
    "@context": "http://schema.org/extensions",
    "summary": "Build Status",
    "sections": [{
        "facts": [{
            "name": "Status",
            "value": "<build status>"
        }]
    }]
}
```

Now I want to update the `<build status>` value as the build progresses and maybe add another fact with download link when the build is finished. Is it possible to update an existing card once it is posted? It seems like a common use case to me, but I was not able to find an answer to it. There are some blogs about updating card as a result of an action, but I don't have or want to have any actions. And obviously I don't want to keep adding cards for the same build process.

Answer (score 1):

Currently update card via web-hook is not supported in teams.